# Why don't Stack Exchange sites use HTTPS redirection?

Tags: discussion, ssl

Shouldn't there be a HTTP -> HTTPS redirect on all Stack Exchange sites?

I am using the HTTPS Everywhere add-on in Chromium, so I am unaffected, but I don't get it.

I see we have a certificate issued from DigiCert SHA2 High Assurance Server CA, which must have cost something.

Moreover, we use [good configuration](https://www.htbridge.com/ssl/?id=43caeae3b2c73d2019d37975a5e61fe2e28d68fd7bf41f8912c0c7260052bba3), which someone must have taken care of, why not use the effort that has been put into it.

I am curious as to what exactly is the problem here?

Comment: There is still some mixed content left, like images that users embedded using `http://` links. SE developers have been converting these, and this work is ongoing, [as Nick Craver tweeted several hours ago](https://twitter.com/Nick_Craver/status/801235862038122496).

Comment: @zaq Mixed content is usually no problem, if not having set strict Content-Security-Policy.

Comment: @VlastimilBurian incorrect - I don't know offhand about Safari/Opera (although Safari at least lags behind everything else in terms of standards support... *sigh*) but Chrome, Firefox and I _think_ IE all block mixed passive content and will probably eventually block mixed active content too.

Comment: Wildcard certificates don't support *.*.stackexchange.com, needed for https://meta.unix.stackexchange.com/

Comment: @strugee It's the other way around, mixed active content from HTTPS to HTTP is blocked by default (at least in Firefox) and blocking mixed passive content is an option.

Comment: @MichaelKjörling whoops! must've gotten the two mixed up somehow. nice catch.

Comment: Actually, when a subdomain of a subdomain needs SSL, like meta.unix.stackexchange.com this is a big topic https://security.stackexchange.com/a/10544/82570

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Stack Exchange has a lot of mixed content which is blocked by modern browsers' Mixed Content Blocker implementations. Ref [Firefox](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Security/Mixed_content), [Chrome](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=513163), [IE/Edge](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/ie/2011/06/23/internet-explorer-9-security-part-4-protecting-consumers-from-malicious-mixed-content/), [W3C editor's draft](https://w3c.github.io/webappsec-mixed-content/).

As pointed out in question comments, Nick Craver [tweeted](https://twitter.com/Nick_Craver/status/801235862038122496) recently that the conversion work is close to being done. He also has [a much older post](https://nickcraver.com/blog/2013/04/23/stackoverflow-com-the-road-to-ssl/) detailing why turning on HTTPS is so complicated (and thus has taken so long) for Stack Exchange.